# Counting Null records not working

Tags: sql, t-sql

```
create table scoda(product varchar(25),price int,sale varchar(23))
insert into scoda values('watch',10,6)
insert into scoda values('socks',8,'NULL')

SELECT COUNT(*) AS GK FROM scoda WHERE sale IS NULL
```

---

```
Expected output:1
Actual output:0
```

help needed to continue i am beginner in sql

Answer (score 4):

USE

```
insert into scoda values('socks',8,NULL)
```

(without quotes).

Answer (score 1):

Problem is in insert statement:

```
insert into scoda values('socks',8,NULL)
```